# Is there any advantage in nodejs calling an async function followed by an await versus a synchronous function?

Tags: node.js

I recently saw this kind of code *in an asynchronous function*:

```
async function foo() {
    const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
    const data = await readFile(file, 'utf8');
    // .... other code
}
```

Is there any advantange of doing this over:

```
async function foo() {
    const data = readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
    // ... other code
}
```

?

In general I am interested in if there is any advantage over calling an asynchronous function followed by an immediate wait on the return, as opposed to calling the corresponding synchronous function without the wait.

And suppose this async function had already been wrapped say in a promise?

*Note: some of the comments and answers refer to an earlier version of this code which was buggy and less clear about the intent.*

Comment: Your second code will not work. The function hasn't been promisified, nor is it synchronous.

Comment: `const data = readFile(file, 'utf8');` wont work. You would require to pass in a callback to be executed once we have data. With `await` you wont have to write callbacks and be saved from callback hell ( http://callbackhell.com )

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of `fs.readFileSync`.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about fs.readFileSync. I should have made it clear I am more interested in calling an async function then an an immediate wait, rather than this specific code.

Comment: `fs.readFileSync` will block the thread while it performs a relative slow read. If you are just processing a file, it probably doesn't matter, but if you are serving incoming requests, you shouldn't block. You will want to be able to serve requests while the file is loading.

Comment: @MarkMeyer See the additional clarification that this is already in an asynchronous function. Sorry for not making all of this clear.

Comment: @rocky your functions don't return anything. In general, if your `async` function doesn't do anything asynchronous, i.e it just calls `fs.readFileSync` then it shouldn't be in an `async` function.

Comment: @rocky it doesn't matter if its in an async function `fs.readFileSync` will still block. While the promisified one will return control to the caller.

Comment: But the await also blocks too, right? And that is immediately done after the call.

Comment: @rocky No it doesn't. If you're awaiting `fs.readFileSync` it will block since eventually you will perform a synchronous operation. If you're awaiting a promisifed version of `fs.readFile` though it won't block.

Comment: No, when `await`ing a promise in an async function doesn't block. The function stops kind of like a generator and the calling code continues. When the awaited promise resolves, if continues to the next await or resolves the promise that was returned by the async function.

Comment: Ok, so the difference then is that with one there is an additional context switch, and that is more lightweight than a thread, but more heavyweight than a simple function call. As others have mentioned for handling errors there may be some benefit to using promises.

Comment: @rocky You're looking for information that can't be given to you in the comments of an SO post. You need to read up on what the Node.js [Event Loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/) is and how it works if you're after that kind of information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your very valid question is that the synchronous methods will block the thread, whereas the async methods will allow other JavaScript to run while the operation takes place, giving your application more room to scale.

For example, if you wrote an http server and only have one request coming in per minute and never simultaneously, it wouldn't matter much what you do. The thread is being blocked for mere milliseconds and that work is unavoidable with respect to the request that is relying on it. However, if you have 100 requests per minute coming through, and maybe some other work being done on some cron schedule in the same JS app, then using the asynchronous methods would allow those requests to continue to come through your server code (JS) while the filesystem work is being done behind the scenes (in C++, I believe, but you'd have to google that part). When the thread is blocked by a synchronous function, then all of those requests and events pile up in the event queue waiting for the JS to handle them, *even though the JS event loop probably isn't busy with anything directly.* It's only waiting. That's not good, so take advantage of the asynchronous nature of single-threaded JS as much as possible.

With respect to error handling, the async versions of those functions have an error object (or `null` when successful) as the callback's first parameter, which is transferred to the `.catch` method when you promisify it. This allows for natural and built-in error handling. You will observe with the `*Sync` functions that there is no callback, and, if it errors, you will not receive that error in a helpful way (usually it crashes the app). Here are two examples to illustrate:

Unhelpful.js

```
const fs = require('fs')
const util = require('util')

const test = fs.readFileSync('./test.js') // spoiler alert: ./test.js doesn't exist

console.log('test:', test) // never runs, because the error thrown is not caught and the process exits :(

/*
Output:

fs.js:113
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './test.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:434:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:339:35)
    ...etc...
*/
```

Better.js

```
const fs = require('fs')
const util = require('util')
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile)

;(async function () {
  // The catch handler actually returns the error object, so test will hold
  // the value/result of the readFile operation whether it succeeds or fails
  const test = await readFile('./test.js').catch(err => err instanceof Error ? err : new Error(err))

  console.log('test:', test)
  // helpful log, as a result:
  // test: { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './test.js'] errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'open', path: './test.js' }
})()
```

Comment: Ok, but does this take into the account the clarification (added after the initial post) that the all of this is already happening inside an aysnchronous function? With respect to error handling, you are I guess suggesting that although there is no error handling in this code, the unseen caller may have code associated  with using a promise, result, right?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter what context you call it in, those `*Sync` functions block the thread until they are completed and return the value or error out.

Comment: Editing my answer, as this is going in depth further than I thought it would lol

Comment: Sorry but I'm still having a problem understanding. Let's suppose this was already inside a promise where the "done" is in the caller somewhere. Or lets say that the caller had already encapsulated this in a separate thread. So yes, the thread blocks, but that has already been isolated in a thread beforehand.

Comment: There is only one thread. When it is blocked, nothing else happens (in your JavaScript). EVERYTHING (in your JS) waits for it to complete.

Comment: Ok. I think I understand now - thanks. Will give this a day to settle before most likely accepting this . Personally, I think adding the clarifications in these comments might help others who may have the same confusion as I had.

Comment: You mean adding the clarifications to my answer? I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

So now that I think I understand the situation, let me try to explain my confusion.

I had thought V8 or nodejs maintained a list of runnable threads even if only one was ever running at a given time. Also I assued that that async functions created a new thread. Thus if that thread was blocked, no problem, because some other runabble thread would be swapped in.

From what people have posted, I now am given to believe that there is only one thread (at least visible to the programmer), so blocking *anywhere* (whether or not there are coroutines/async functions) blocks *everywhere*.